# How do I display the region to which Azure Traffic Manager has directed the user?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

We want to display the region to which users are being directed by Azure Traffic Manager in our MVC 4 application (we have cloud services set up in Europe, Asia, and the US). We're thinking of handling this similarly to the way we display the version number in the footer (so it would say something like Version: 1.5.7 Region: East US). I've heard this can be done but I have no idea how. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosted service in Europe would say "Region: Europe" for every single request that comes to it.  Similarly, your hosted service in Asia would say "Region: Asia" for every single request that it receives.  When WATM sends a user to the Europe service then the user would see "Region: Europe".

The Cloud Cover Episode 46 shows a sample of this.  http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-46-Windows-Azure-Traffic-Manager

Comment: This Ch9 video, shows regions from a lookup table, but it's not originating from Traffic Manager. So if you spend the 47 minutes watching this, you'll find that it's not the answer you're looking for

Comment: Scott, I think you might be confused about either the question, the answer, or the traffic manager video.  The background color and the region name displayed on the home page in the video is coming from, essentially, a hard coded value in each service itself (they are settings in the CSCFG file).  The only thing coming from a lookup table is the service up/down flag, but that has nothing to do with the question that was asked.  If you think the video is showing something different from what I am saying please feel free to give a timestamp and description...